# javascript image slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I've made a  javscript code to rotate 3 images every 2 seconds.But it doesn't execute properly.I only see the first image.I'm a beginner at javascript.Please explain what i'm doing wrong.Also,could anyone suggest a good book on javascript.

Here's the code:_

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>slide</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    img1=new Image();
    img1.src="arch.jpg";
    img2=new Image();
    img2.src="apartments.jpg";
    img3=new Image();   
    img3.src="streets.jpg";
    -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function slide(i)
     {

     if(i==1)
      {
      document.getElementById("pic").src=img2.src;

      }
      if(i==2)
       {
        document.getElementById("pic").src=img3.src;

       }
      if(i==3)
       {
        document.getElementById("pic").src=img1.src;

       }    

       if(i<3)
       {
       i++;
       setTimeout("slide(i)",2000);
       }
       else
       {
       i=1;
       setTimeout("slide(1)",2000);
       }

     }

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click",setTimeout("slide(1)",2000),false);
    </script>

    <img src="arch.jpg" id="pic"></img>
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="button"></input>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout("slide(i)",2000);` is never going to do what you think you want it to do...

Answer (score 0):

You use setTimeout not quite correctly, after the delay parameter you can pass some other values(*"a string"*) that the callback function is going to receive:

```
setTimeout(function(val){
  console.log(val);// "a string"
},1000,"a string");
```

It's worth trying to pass variable *i* as third parameter into setTimeout:

```
if(i<3)
{
   setTimeout(slide,2000,++i);
}
else
{
   i=1;
   setTimeout(slide,2000,i);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude yet functional one I just put together. Noticed how I used setTimeout, also as you can see there are ways to condense your slide function as well..

```
var i=0,
baseUrl = 'http://i.imgur.com/',
images = ['la7nDkI','Kdmzy1z','RtelUKm'],

slide = function(index){
    document.getElementById('pic').src = baseUrl + images[i] + '.png';  
},

loop = function(){

    setTimeout(loop, 1000);

    slide(i);

    i++;

    if(i === images.length){
        i=0;
    }

};

loop();
```